# Facebook ads api flow server side

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, ads

Is there a way to request [Facebook ads api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access) without getting an access token though a web interface (*with oauth delegation*)?

Looking [at the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/chapter-1-Setup-and-Authentication) it's all about redirect and oauth classic login steps.

But a server may need to gather data without human contribution; it's not doable to display a Facebook login screen every two weeks to get a new valid access token.

Can this access token be generated through an api call?

```
// this call generates an app token, but end up with an exception
// "You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action"
// on every api call relative to campaign, creative & co

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={id}&client_secret={secret}
```

I'm missing something?

```
// Using the php ads sdk

use FacebookAds\Api;
Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

// where app_id and app_secret can be found in the ad account preferences
// and access_token has to be generated — but how?
```

Comment: Depends on what kind of access token you need. User access tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days, after that, you’ll have to go through the login flow again, as it is the only way to generate user access tokens.

Comment: User access token seems the only way to get access to the ads api endpoints. But it seems that user access token can only be generated through client side steps with oauth delegation — preventing a "server only" solution

Comment: Yes, generating a user access token requires client-side interaction.

Comment: Do you mean that client side interaction are compulsory to use the api server side? This seems incredible to me that full server-to-server interactions are not available.

Comment: If you want to act on behalf of a user (which is what using user access tokens does), then yes, the client-side part is compulsory, because using a browser/client device is the only way for users to authenticate with Facebook.

Comment: I don't. I just want to request the ads api to create campaign & co on the app account. I don't see where this implies a user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This steps are working.

- Get a short-lived token (*with the `manage_pages` permission*) though the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)
- Convert this short-lived access token into a long-lived one though https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=
- Convert this long-lived access token in a permanent one (Expires: Never) though https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=